# AWS SES limit request

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, cloud, amazon-ses

I want to increase SES limits in my AWS accounts but amazon rejects my request everytime. If anyone could help me in doing that.

I have even mailed amazon but no reply , they called me on friday stating that they will increase my limits by today but havent done yet.

Please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not Amazon Customer Support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/2988).

Answer (score 0):

You need to give proper need to increase and you need to justify to them that you need it. You need to show them you proper convenient usage of service

And for SES you need to deploy handler for bounces and complaints to get higher limits

And you are not assured that whatever limit you ask for they won't give you directly

i.e. if you ask for 1000 limit and they may give you 1000 or else 800 or anything below 1000

Being honest with them in every single detail will help you out

They have our usage data with in-depth details, each and every single log so using that they ensure you require it

Comment: We have already done that. Mentioned each and every detail to them.

Comment: Then there is no way rather than discussing this directly to AWS Support